# Click button after event finished

Tags: javascript

Why in the following code I can not click the button programmatically to translate the `div` again ?

```js
const div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[0];

div1.addEventListener("transitionend", callback);
// Why this one does not work?
// div1.addEventListener("transitionend", play);

function play() {
  div1.classList.add("play");
}

function callback() {
  div1.classList.remove("play");
  // or this one?
  // play();
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.play {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<button onclick="play()">Play</button>
```

Comment: it's not clear when you want to click the button - during the animation or not

Comment: I want an animation loop for a carousel without using `setInterval`.

Comment: then your description is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no effect to changing the class instantly.

that is why you should use `setTimeOut` to call `play` again

```js
const div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[0];

div1.addEventListener("transitionend", callback);

function play() {
  div1.classList.add("play");
}

function callback() {
  div1.classList.remove("play");
  setTimeout(play);
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.play {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<button onclick="play()">Play</button>
```

you might also use css animation to get the same effect with cleaner code

```js
const div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[0];

function play() {
  div1.classList.add("play");
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.play {
  animation: go-right 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes go-right {
  100%{
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<button onclick="play()">Play</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I wonder why we need a delay!

Comment: @Dante make it clear in the answer what you mean by clicking again, otherwise the question isn't clear what you want. this answer is about endless animation, not clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

When you click the "Play" button, the `play` function is called and it adds the "`play`" class to `div1`. This triggers a transition and when the transition ends, the callback function is called, which removes the "`play`" class.

If you want to toggle the translation on/off with button click modify the `play` function to add or remove the "`play`" class based on whether it's there

```
function play() {
  if (div1.classList.contains("play")) {
    div1.classList.remove("play");
  } else {
    div1.classList.add("play");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stop the animation with removing the `play` class and start it again with adding the `play` class after a zero timeout (that allows the browser to re-render and start the animation fresh):

```
  if(div1.classList.contains('play')){
    div1.classList.remove('play');
    setTimeout(()=>div1.classList.add('play'));
    return;
  }
```

```js
const div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[0];

div1.addEventListener("transitionend", callback);
// Why this one does not work?
// div1.addEventListener("transitionend", play);

function play() {
  if(div1.classList.contains('play')){
    div1.classList.remove('play');
    setTimeout(()=>div1.classList.add('play'));
    return;
  }
  div1.classList.add("play");
  
}

function callback() {
  div1.classList.remove("play");
  // or this one?
  // play();
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.play {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<button onclick="play()">Play</button>
```